# how to iterate between multiple 2-dimensional arrays that share a value in common?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, search, for-loop

how can I iterate between multiple 2 dimensional arrays. For example, I want to find   all students who reside in Cobb, were born after 1970 and received a C or better in a course taught by Evan Duggan. The two tables share n common the user ID for example "0033"

```
 public class JavaApplication2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
  String [ ][ ] students = {
                        { "0033", "Sandra", "Smith", "Cobb", "1989" },
                        { "1144", "Bo", "Harrison", "DeKalb","1987" },
                        { "2255", "Sam", "Mitchell", "Cobb", "1969"},
                        { "3366", "Sabrina", "Jones", "Cobb", "1979"},
                        { "4477", "Harry", "Johnson", "Cobb", "1982"},
                        { "5588", "Lisa", "Simpson", "Paulding", "1982"}
                        };

  String[ ][ ] grades = {
                        { "5588", "201405", "CSE", "1301J", "A", "Ian Salts" },
                        { "5588", "201405", "COMM", "2400","B", "Evan Duggan" },
                        { "5588", "201408", "CSE", "1302J", "A", "Ian Salts"},
                        { "0033", "201405", "CSE", "1301J", "C", "Ian Salts"},
                        { "0033", "201405", "COMM", "2400", "A", "Evan Duggan"}
                        };




       for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
       {
              System.out.print(students[ i ] [ 0 ] + ": ");
              for (int j = 1; j < students[ i ].length; j++)
              {
                         System.out.print(students[ i ][ j ] + " ");
              }
             System.out.println( );
       }
         System.out.println( );
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
       {
              System.out.print(grades[ i ] [ 0 ] + ": ");
              for (int j = 1; j < grades[ i ].length; j++)
              {
                         System.out.print(grades[ i ][ j ] + " ");
              }
             System.out.println( );

       }

        for ( int i=0; i<grades.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j< grades[i].length; j++) {
    if ( grades[i][j].equals("A") && grades [i][5].equals("Evan Duggan")) {
        System.out.println("The student ID is "+ grades[i][0]);

    }
    else if ( grades[i][j].equals("B") && grades [i][5].equals("Evan Duggan")){
        System.out.println("The student ID is "+ grades[i][0]);
       }
    else if ( grades[i][j].equals("C") && grades [i][5].equals("Evan Duggan")){
        System.out.println("The student ID is "+ grades[i][0]);
    }

}


}

 }
 }
```

Comment: I'd start by thinking about how you would do this by hand.  Iterate through the first array, and when you see one where the element you want is `"Cobb"`, then look at the ID in that array element, iterate through the second array looking for the ID ...

Comment: By the way, the right way to do this isn't with a multi-dimensional array.  Instead, you'd define a `Student` class that maintains all those fields separately, and similarly a `Grade` class.  And instead of an ID field, you'd probably want the `Grade` class to have a reference to a `Student`; and you can use a `Map` so that you can look up the students by ID.  But if these are all concepts you haven't learned yet, then I just gave you something to look forward to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you *have* to work with 2-dimensional arrays, you can solve this problem by grouping and matching the criteria relevant to each array:

```
for (String[] student: students) {
   // First set of criteria relevant to students array
   if (student[3].equals("Cobb") && Integer.parseInt(student[4]) > 1970) {

       for (String[] grade: grades) {
          // Match on student id as well as criteria relevant to grades array
          if (grade[0].equals(student[0]) && grade[5].equals("Evan Duggan"))  {

             // I separate the conditionals here to keep it readable/tidy
             // Consider using a Enum type or comparator etc.
             if (grade[4].equals("C") || grade[4].equals("B") || grade[4].equals("A")) {
                // Code for handling matching student
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```